# Component only rending if I start the flow from the homepage

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-redux

I am having an issue with my application. My user component only loads UserCard when I start the application from the homepage then click users link there... if I just refresh the users URL... UserCard doesn't get loaded which means something is wrong with my `this.props.users`. I do see that in chrome it says: `Value below was evaluated just now` when I refresh but when I go through the flow it doesn't say that. Any help will be appreciated.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            users: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        users = []
        axios.get('/getall').then((res) => {
            for(var d in res.data) {
                users.push(new User(res.data[d]));
            }
        });
    this.setState({ users });
    }

    render() {
        const { users } = this.state;
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path='/users' render={(props) => <Users {...props} users={users} />}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

PrivateRoute:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        <Component {...props} /> )} />
)
```

User.js

```
export default class Users extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.users);
        return (
            <Row>
                {this.props.users.map(u =>
                        <UserCard key={u.name} user={u}/>
                )}
            </Row>
        );
    }
}

export class User {
    constructor(obj) {
        for (var prop in obj){
            this[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }

    getURLName() {
        return this.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    }
}

class UserCard extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Link to={'/users/' + this.props.user.getURLName()} >
                <div>
                    // Stuff Here
                </div>
            </Link>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You're modifying `this.state` directly in `componentDidMount`. You should be using `this.setState`. (this is probably where your issue is arising). Probably unrelated, but you are also supplying `<UserCard />` with a `user` prop and then you reference `this.props.users.getURLName()` inside `UserCard` (should it not be `this.props.user.getURLName()` instead? this may be just a typo in the question since that would error out pretty quickly when running your app.)

Comment: @StuartBourhill second point was a typo. I use this.setState as well but same results. UserCard doesn't get called on page refresh only when I go through the whole flow

Comment: Updated the code in question to reflect it

Comment: there's some really sketchy things here. Only ever use this.setState to modify state. If you must, `let x = this.state.x; dothingsto(x); this.setState({ x });`. Also, don't wholesale rebind `this[prop] = obj[prop]`, all your code is saying there is "I didn't write my user class properly and made debugging insanely much harder because I have no idea which functions and properties should be callable". Finally, you probably want to turn that UserCare into a `function(props) { return <Link .... >; }`, rather than a class, since you're not relying on state in any way there.

Comment: Can you show the relevant react-router bits for your main and user routes, too? Because those determine exactly what gets run.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans updated question for you.

Comment: When you call `setState` to set `users`, it should called in `then`. Your request hasn't come back and you've already set your component state to an empty array of users.

Comment: @StuartBourhill That fixed it!! wow, such a simple mistake. Do you think I can clean up my code further? especially in the setting state part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

The issue here is how you're setting state. You should never modify state directly since this will not cause the component to rerender [See the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Some additional thoughts unrelated to the question:

- As per the comments - use function components whenever possible, especially with [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) on the way
- There is probably no need to create a `User` class, only to `new` up little user objects. Simply use plain old JS objects and calculate the link url right in the place its used:

---

```
render() {
  const { user } = this.props
  return <Link to={`/users/${user.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}`} />
}
```

- It might be a good idea to start using a linter such as eslint. I see that you're declaring `users = []` without using `let` or `const` (don't use `var`). This is bad practice since creating variables in this way pollutes the global name space. Linters like eslint will help you catch issues like this while you're coding.

Comment: What is the upside for function components?